# How to use knitr from command line with Rscript and command line argument?

Tags: r, knitr

I have an R code `my_code.R` which takes in an argument a file `test.txt`. I can use:

```
   Rscript -e my_code.R test.txt
```

and run the script, but i want to use stitch() from knitR to generate the report of the script in pdf/tex.

I have trolled around stack overflow and used following suggestions, but didn't get any results:

```
   Rscript -e "library(knitr);knit('my_code.R "-args arg1=test.txt" ')"
   Rscript -e "knitr::stitch('my_code.R "-args arg1=test.txt"')"
```

Here is another similar discussion on what i want ([link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/knitr/command$20line$20stitch/knitr/UJO7yZVd8og/tgK84SsE5DcJ)), but with option for adding argument(s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not see why this is not possible. Here is `my_code.R`:

```
commandArgs(TRUE)
```

And I simply run

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); stitch('my_code.R')" --args foo bar whatever=blabla
```

I get the output

[image: knitr stitch() output]

It seems you did not use double quotes correctly in your original attempt. It should be

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); stitch('my_code.R')" --args arg1=test.txt
```

Comment: Note that `stitch` is for `.R` and `knit` is for `.Rnw`. This answer isn't wrong, but I missed that subtlety and went down a rabbithole for awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `knit2pdf`and pass parameters to the report using its `envir` argument.

In other words , the solution is to create 2 seperates files an :

- R script where you call `knit2pdf` like this : `m_code.R`
- a markdown report file (.Rnw,.Rmd) : `m_code_report.Rnw`

#### m_code.R

This script contains all you R code. The idea, is to create an environment variable "params" , where you put all parameters need to be displayed/presented.

```
library(knitr)
library(markdown)
ff <- commandArgs(TRUE)[1]
params <- new.env()
e$ff <- ff
## here I pass all the parameters to the report
## I assume that the report and the code R in the same location
## the result pdf also will be in the same location , otherwise you can set 
## paths as you like  
knit2pdf('m_code_report.Rnw',envir=params)  report
```

#### m_code_report.Rnw

The report display resulted using variables contained in the environment "params".

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
summary(ff)
@
\end{document}
```

Then you call the Rscript using Rscript for example like this:

```
Rscript m_code.R "cars"
```

Comment: I am not sure if i understand this correctly, but does this mean a separate .Rnw file needs to be created, and how are two files connected?

Comment: @mshakya I edit my answer to add more explanations. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Oh this is great, i think i got it work using this, but is it possible not to have to use the .Rnw file, and to would run the script as you would do using stitch() function. Thank you

Comment: I think this is what i want but with an option to take in the arguments.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/knitr/command$20line$20stitch/knitr/UJO7yZVd8og/tgK84SsE5DcJ

Comment: I don'know this function, but I think you can its env argument like what I did in this answer.

Comment: Yeah, it works great, but i am not sure how would i integrate this in my Makefile without making a .Rnw file for each of my argument file `test.txt`.

Comment: But the way i had setup makes `m_code_report.pdf` over and over. How can i get to write a different file for each different `test.txt`